# Django - ошибка DoesNotExist при object.get(id=)

Tags: django

Всем привет! Изучаю Django меньше недели. Создаю простое приложение для различных товаров (создание, показ и удаление) по туториалу. Откуда не возьмись вылетает ошибка во views **DoesNotExist** при попытке **получить объект по id**: `obj = Product.objects.get(id=1)`.

Насколько я понял, ошибка означает что объект не существует. Но я могу увидеть все объекты через admin и `Product.objects.all()` выдает `<QuerySet [<Product: Pancakes>, <Product: Cookies>]>` - мои объекты.

Гуглил - рекомендуют засунуть в `try except` или делать через `get_object_or_404()`. Вот только смысла нет никакого, я как не мог получить доступ к существующему объекту, так и не могу.

**products/views**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Product

def show(request, id):
    obj = Product.objects.get(id=id)
    context = {
        'obj': obj,
    }
    return render(request, 'products/show.html', context)
```

**products/models**

```
from django.db import models    

class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10000)
```

**Сама ошибка **

```
Internal Server Error: /product/1/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Coding\Django practice\learn\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Coding\Django practice\learn\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Coding\Django practice\learn\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Coding\Django practice\learn\products\views.py", line 27, in show
    obj = Product.objects.get(id=id)
  File "C:\Coding\Django practice\learn\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Coding\Django practice\learn\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 408, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
products.models.Product.DoesNotExist: Product matching query does not exist.
```

*Заранее спасибо!*

Comment: Вы саму БД смотрели? Там есть запись с таким ID?

Comment: @V-Mor, как можно посмотреть БД?

Comment: В зависимости от используемой СУБД существуют различные средства просмотра. У Вас какая?

Comment: @V-Mor sqlite3,

Comment: @V-Mor посмотрел, у всех записей ID почему-то начинается не с 1, а с 5. Возможно удалял некоторые. Можно как-то избежать этого? Чтобы при удалении ID смещались и все начиналось с 1?

Comment: Если ID задаёте не сами, нет. Бывает в некоторых СУБД и такое что идёт 1, 2, 3, 4... и тут резко 5056, 5057... А для Вашей СУБД есть SQLite Studio

Comment: Лучше ищите не по ID, а по какому-то другому параметру. Например, сделайте своё подобие ID.

Comment: И да, *Чтобы при удалении ID смещались и все начиналось с 1?* тогда у Вас вечно будут разные ID у одних и тех же записей и ID потеряет своё основное свойство – быть уникальным идентификатором записи

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вынесу из комментариев в ответ:

Ваша проблема в том, что в БД действительно не существует записей с таким ID, т.к. СУБД проставляет "свои" ID по "одной ей известным" правилам.

Решением в данном случае может стать создание собственного поля – аналога ID. Однако ни в коем случае не забывайте, что **главное назначение ID – уникальная идентификация записи**, а не обозначение порядкового номера в таблице. То есть, даже если Вы создадите свой аналог ID, будет неверным решением "сдвигать" ID записей при удалении одной или нескольких из них.